# FileSystemWallet() not working in google cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

FileSystemWallet() not working in google cloud function, can anyone raise this bug in jira? I tried to implement invoke transaction using gateway which we need to use FileSystemWallet() to read the certs in the wallet folder, it always returns false.

```
 exports.invoke = async function(req, res) {

     const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), './wallet');
        const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);
        console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

        // Check to see if we've already enrolled the user.
        const userExists = await wallet.exists('user1');
      console.log(userExists);
        if (!userExists) {
            console.log('An identity for the user "user1" does not exist in the wallet');
            console.log('Run the registerUser.js application before retrying');
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write outside of the /tmp directory, which is the [only directory that Cloud Functions allow to write in](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system):

> The only writeable part of the filesystem is the /tmp directory, which
>   you can use to store temporary files in a function instance.

Try writing there and don’t forget to delete the files when you don’t need them anymore, as not doing so can cause some [issues with memory](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#always_delete_temporary_files):

> Local disk storage in the temporary directory is an in-memory
>   filesystem. Files that you write consume memory available to your
>   function, and sometimes persist between invocations.